# check if program is stuck in a loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, loops, cocos2d-iphone

ok...so i'm randomly generating a level in a class and then pass it to the game.

The problem is that when i generate the level sometimes it gets stuck in a loop ( due to the checks i do when i generate it). I've tried to reduce the number of freezes by modifying the code..but it still gets stuck in like 1~2 % if the cases.

in RandomLevel i have this:

```
-(void)positionMonsters:(int)nrM{

int nrH=[randomHero count];

int rdm;
CGPoint randPt;
BOOL is;



while ([randomMonsters count]!=nrM) {
    rdm=arc4random()%(nrH-1);

    if (rdm!=nrH-1) {
    randPt=random_on_line([[randomHero objectAtIndex:rdm]position], [[randomHero objectAtIndex:rdm+1]position ], CCRANDOM_0_1());
    }else{
    randPt=random_on_line([[randomHero objectAtIndex:rdm]position], [[randomHero objectAtIndex:0]position ], CCRANDOM_0_1());
    }

    is=NO;
    for (Monster *mob in randomMonsters) {
        if (ccpFuzzyEqual(randPt, mob.position, 40)) {
            is=YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!is) {
        Monster *mob=[[Monster alloc]initWithPosition:randPt];
        [randomMonsters addObject:mob];
    }




}
```

}

let me walk you through the code :

so i get the count of heros (how many there), as long as there aren't as many monsters as i want to make, i chose a random line between 2 consecutive heros and generate a point on that line, then i check if the point generated is close to any other (i don't want the to overlap).. if it is then it starts the loop again, if it's not i add it to the random mobs

it get's stuck when i check if the mob overlaps another ...but i shouldn't because the heros are always at least 200 px apart and i only make a handfull of mobs.

in my GameScene i do this:

```
-(id)init{
//stuff stuff
RandomLevel *rlv=[[RandomLevel alloc]initWithHeros:6 andMonsters:6]; *****

heros=rlv.randomHeros;
mobs=rlv.randomMonsters;
}
```

what i want is to stop / cancel the `*****` line and try to get a random level again ...as i said.. this only happens only 1% of the cases so it wouldn't be such a big deal if the game "freezes" for 2 sec every week ..or something

Comment: If you're wondering how to determine if you're stuck in a loop, then you have structured your code incorrectly. I know it's not much of an answer, but it's the truth.

Comment: i know where and how it gets stuck but i can't do anything about it without using huge amount of processing power

Comment: I think there are edge cases where this behavior is okay as long as you comment the code thoroughly, there's a big performance savings, and it isn't just a band-aid solution.  You could always check and see how many times the loop has been hit and estimate based on some tests how many times it aught to be hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use `performSelector:withDelay` and cancel it within your loop if before it ends?

Comment: just tried it...it stops the loop and then the game crashes all together

Comment: okay. With the following modifications you should be able to leave the loop where you get stuck (at least if the app didn't crash). Before your RandomLevel alloc/init method include this:    __block BOOL stopLoop = FALSE;
    
    double delayInSeconds = .5;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, self.bgQueue, ^(void){
            stopLoop = TRUE;
    });
and in you stuck loop include right before ccpFuzzyEqual line: if (stopLoop) break; So a monster for that point wont find its way into the Monsters array.

Comment: your code is exactly what i needed..but incomplete. you forgot to mention you need to create bgQueue (or you need to for the 2nd gen ipod i'm using). On a more positive side..i think i finally understood multithreading thanks to you..so yea..Thank you

Comment: ;) I leave the bgQueue creation as an excersice to you

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would break out of your loop if processing takes more than .5 seconds.  Of course you would modify it for your specific case.

```
NSDate* myTime= [NSDate date];
while (true)
{
   ...

   if ([myTime timeIntervalSinceNow] < -0.5])
   {
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Experienced software engineers will tell you that if you're using something like this, you have structural problems in your code. Since engineering is often a profession the requires pragmatism, such a solution can be necessary. But they should be avoided if possible. :)